# Setting unexpected date time when selecting the first available date from the Kendo date time picker and the client time zone is UTC -

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid in my Asp.net MVC application,  When I am selecting the first available date[min date time] from my kendo grid date picker, I am getting expected date but the time is different when client time zone is UTC- (eg: UTC-8 Pacific time US & Canada) , it’s setting  the time as 16:00(this value is based on the UTC-  please refer the below table) instead of the min hour and minute, this problem is happening only when the date input field[Value()] is empty, Please find the scenario below

[image]

Note: The code is deployed in India and the URL is accessed from different time zone

> This is working fine as expected if the user time zone is UTC + 00 or
>   UTC +  and if the code deployed time zone and user browser time zone
>   are same

**Problem scenario(Client time zone UTC – and the date time input field is empty):**

Code deployed in India and user accessing from Arizona (UTC – 07:00)
Date picker min date time : 28/08/2019 03:47 AM

[image]

Now select the first available date, it’s setting 17: 00 instead of 03:47 in the time field

[image]

[image]

**Working scenario(Client time zone UTC -   and the date time input filed is not empty):**

Date picker min date time : 28/08/2019 03:47 AM

Here my date input field is having some date and time, I select the first available date, now it’s setting 03:47 in the time field as expected, this scenario is working fine.

[image]

[image]

below is my smaple code:

```
var DateTemplate = DateHeader + " <br>" + @Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
                                    .Name("EnrolmentDatePickerHeader")
                                    .Events(events => events.Change("DetailsPage.HeaderSelectionChange"))
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "span-field" })
                                    .Interval(30)
                                    //.Value("")
                                    .Min(Model.MinAllowedDate)
                                    .Max(Model.MaxAllowedDate);
```

Can somebody help me out on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kendo's default behavior, The time which is getting set for selecting first available date is the time difference between the client timezone and the time zone where the code is deployed.
For ex:
The code is deployed in UK and user accessing from India, So the time difference 5.30 will be set when selecting first available date when the date input field is empty.